# Sensitivity of human eye v.s. photodiode or photomultiplier?

Tags: optics, visible-light, sensor

I am working with optical detectors and I would like to explain to friends how small 1 pW of optical power emitted at $\lambda$ = 550 nm is related to the sensibility of the human eye.

My idea is to simply demonstrate at which distance a $1 \text{mm}^2$ photodiode has to be from a candela to only receive 1 pW.

So one candela is $1/683 [\frac{\text{W}}{\text{st}}]$ which is about $4\pi/683=18 [\text{mW}]$. With $S$ the surface of my detector and $r$ the distance from the light source. I can write:

$$
\frac{1}{683}\cdot\frac{S}{R^2}=P
$$

Where $P$ is the measured intensity.

Thus for detecting 1 pW I must place my detector at:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{683}\cdot\frac{S}{P}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{683}\cdot\frac{(1\cdot 10^{-3})^2}{1\cdot 10^{-12}}} = r = 38 [\text{m}]
$$

Which is not the value I was expecting. I often read that a naked human eye is able to detect a candela from about 2 kilometers. That means either my calculus is completely wrong or a photodetector with a 1 pW sensitivity is a poor detector.

Could someone explain my misunderstanding?

**EDIT**

From another approach I read [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html) that the human eye is capable of detecting 100 photos emitted in a 1 ms flash. So the energy of 100 photos is about:

$$
100\cdot\frac{h\cdot c}{\lambda} = 360\cdot 10^{-21} [\text{J}]
$$

As the human eye have an integration time of about 100 ms. I can make the assumption that the human eye has a sensitivity of:

$$
360\cdot 10^{-21} [\text{J}] \cdot \frac{1}{100} = 3.6\cdot 10^{-21} [\text{W}]
$$

Is that possible?